# Large string as primary key

Tags: database, database-design, primary-key, large-data

I'm interested in use a database system that allows me to set a primary key field that will contain variable length strings that can reach 50.000 characters in length.

As the string length is variable, storing a relatively short string on relational database system will cause significant waste of space so, there is a NoSQL database system that makes this possible?

**EDIT**

This large strings are base64-encoded images. When I get an encoded image I have to generate data from it and give a response. Generate the data takes time and the images can repeat, this motivates the storing of the image and associated data. To fetch data associated to specific image, the query should ask for the image itself because it's all I receive

Comment: I'd suggest you use a hash of the string instead.

Comment: Hashes can collide. They're good for partitioning a set, not for identifying a set.

Comment: Please explain the use case that requires such large primary keys.